# how to calculate the time difference between the values in column over midnight?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp

I have a column of timestamp values for each hour for 25 days. I want to take the time difference between them. I have tried the code in the past but it gives me a negative value. I have this new code, but it is for two values, but how can I tweak it to loop over the values of column?

```
def time_diff(start, end):
    if isinstance(start, datetime_time): # convert to datetime
        assert isinstance(end, datetime_time)
        start, end = [datetime.combine(datetime.min, t) for t in [start, end]]
    if start <= end: # e.g., 10:33:26-11:15:49
        return end - start
    else: # end < start e.g., 23:55:00-00:25:00
        end += timedelta(1) # +day
        assert end > start
        return end - start
```

Comment: if `dif <0: dif=24+dif`?

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output. Copy and paste for example `print(df.head())`

Comment: This is the normal code i tried     *dataFrame['Time_diff'] = (dataFrame.groupby(['DeviceName', 'Date'])['Time_ist_td'].diff().dt.total_seconds())//60*

Comment: if i remove 'Date' from groupby, it will give negative time difference at midnight  Ex: '23:55:00 - 00:25:00'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: why are you pasting this link?

Comment: We need a data frame and an expected output to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: ```index timestamp diff
1 22:08:08 0
2 22:38:06 30
3 23:07:48 29
4 23:37:28 30
5 00:07:10 30
6 00:37:08 30
```

Comment: sorry i dont know how to paste it

Comment: copy and paste the output of your dataframe head print(df.head()) in your question. I can edit

Comment: show output of : `dataFrame['Time_diff'] = (dataFrame.groupby(['DeviceName'])['Time_ist_td'].diff().dt.total_seconds())//60` or `dataFrame['Time_diff'] = (dataFrame.groupby(['DeviceName'])['Time_ist_td'].diff()`

Comment: this code i used initially. here the problem is, around mid night i get negative time difference because 23:00 - 00:00 gives negative minutes

Comment: Date_Time Date Time_ist Time_diff
```39 2019-10-01 23:51:00 2019-10-01 23:51:00 29.0
40 2019-10-02 00:21:00 2019-10-02 00:21:00 -1410.0```

Comment: 39 and 40 are index

Comment: try use Series.where: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html 
to change the sign to the minutes or modify it when negative as I have proposed in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
s = dataFrame.groupby(['DeviceName'])['Time_ist_td'].diff()
dataFrame['Time_diff']=s.where(s>pd.Timedelta(0),-s).dt.total_seconds()) // 60
```

---

**basic idea:**

```
s=pd.Series([-1,1])
print(s)

0   -1
1    1
dtype: int64
s=s.where(s>0,-s)
print(s)

0    1
1    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) This is the code i used initially, but at mid night i used to get negative value. But your initial answer ```dif <0: dif=24+dif``` gave me hint. After doing groupby and getting the difference, I will pass a loop to add "24*60" to the values less than zero :) Thank you

Comment: I hope you understood the problem i was facing. The trick i mentioned above will work right?